# Is the class NSC closed under complement?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

The class $\mathsf{NSC}$ is defined as $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mathsf{NSC}^k$, where $\mathsf{NSC}^k = \mathsf{NTIMESPACE}[\mathsf{poly},\mathsf{log}^k]$.
In a 1991 paper [Mix Barrington and McKenzie](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089054019190017V) ask the question of whether $\mathsf{NSC}^2$ is closed under complement.

Has there been any progress on that question for $\mathsf{NSC}$ in general or for particular values of $k$?

Comment: I don't think there has been.  I guess that Ryan Williams would know, so we should wait for him to chime in, but both authors that you mention are not on cstheory.SE; you may try contacting them if this becomes inconclusive.

Comment: It is not known whether NSC is closed under complement.  I would conjecture that it's not -- but this isn't based on much.  I've written two papers that deal with NSC, and I regret that neither of them cites [Barrington, McKenzie].  They are:  http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/cjtcs.2013.005 and http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2014.v010a012  There aren't many other papers of which I'm aware that deal with NSC.  The three of which I am aware are: https://doi.org/10.1145/3154856 https://doi.org/10.1145/3188745.3188924 and https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1250.pdf

Comment: Oops: One more: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1250.pdf